# Catching any exception and actually do something with it

Tags: c++, error-handling

Say I have a framework, which should catch *any* exceptions raised from user code, and actually do something with it, such as converting it to a return value

```cpp
namespace framework
{
    template<class Handler>
    status do_stuff(Handler handler)
    {
        try
        {
            return handler();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            return status{ «something» };
        }
    }
}
```

I came up with this solution:

```cpp
namespace framework
{
    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, status(*)(std::exception_ptr)> exception_converters;

    template<class T>
    void register_exception_class()
    {
        exception_converters[std::type_index{typeid(T)}] = [](std::exception_ptr eptr){
            try
            { std::rethrow_exception(eptr); }
            catch(T const& obj)
            { return to_status(obj); }
        };
    }

    status catch_any(std::exception_ptr eptr)
    {
        auto const exception_type = eptr.__cxa_exception_type();
        if(auto get_message = exception_converters.find(std::type_index{*exception_type});
            get_message != std::end(exception_converters))
        { return get_message->second(eptr); }
        else
        { return status{ «some default value» }; }
    }

    // Handler is specific to client code
    template<class Handler>
    status do_stuff(Handler handler)
    {
        try
        {
            return handler();
        }
        catch(std::exception const& e)
        { 
            // Conversion handled by the framework
            return to_status(e);
        }
        catch(...)
        { return catch_any(std::current_exception()); }
    }
}
```

If not deriving from `std::exception`, the client code may call `register_exception_class`, that will use typeid to store a function pointer, to a function taking an `exception_ptr`, which is rethrown, and converted by calling `to_status` found by ADL. I may consider a template specialization also.

When the exception is caught, the converter is searched for in the table, and is called.

To make the example shorter, I have ignored the obvious fact that the table needs to be guarded by a mutex, and also technicalities about static initialization order fiasco. Here, I am more interesting in

- Whether or not it is acceptable to poke into `eptr` to find its rtti information
- If there is a better way to get T out from `eptr` other than rethrowing it an then
  capture it.
- If it is practical to be able to register a handler in this way, or it is better to simply always

```
return status{ «some default value» };
```

For unknown exception types.

Comment: We don't review hypothetical code, we only review working code from a project you have written. This question is off-topic because it is not asking for a review of existing working code.

Answer (score 1):

The only¹ portable thing we can do with a `std::exception_ptr` is pass it to `std::rethrow_exception()`.  Since the standard specifies no members, it follows that calling `eptr.__cxa_exception_type()` is at best implementation-defined, and more likely dependent on undocumented internals which can change or disappear without notice in a future version of your compiler.

We *could* permit applications to register functions which re-throw the exception and catch the ones they understand (we'd have to call them sequentially, of course, but performance isn't a major concern in the error-handling path).

It might be simpler to return the `std::exception_ptr` as an alternative return value using `std::variant` or [`std::expected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected).  But we're not adding any value by doing that; it's probably best to let exceptions do their natural thing and allow the caller to catch them.

---

¹ Well, we must be able to make copies, and to destruct it as well, but I'll take those as given.

Comment: Though you sometimes cannot leak any exception, for example at an ABI boundary or in an event loop that must keep going. I interpret your answer as it is not worth it to try to do something more fancy than swallow exceptions you do not understand.